# Cond wait and signal across processes in C

Tags: c, process, clang, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to replicate a simple producer-consumer problem with processes (bear-honey-bees). So far I was able to sync the bees so that only one produces honey at the time. However, when it comes the time for the bear to consume it seems be stuck on the waiting condition.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef struct Pot {
   int honey;
   int size;
} Pot;  

pthread_mutex_t * pot_lock = NULL;
pthread_mutexattr_t lock_properties;

pthread_cond_t * can_use_pot = NULL;
pthread_condattr_t condition_properties;

int main(int arc, char* argv[]){
  int fd[2]; 
  int total_bees = 10;
  int created_bees = 0;

  pthread_mutexattr_init(&lock_properties);
  pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&lock_properties, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  //edit: previously using malloc
  pot_lock = (pthread_mutex_t*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); 
  //---      
  pthread_mutex_init(pot_lock, &lock_properties);

  pthread_condattr_init(&condition_properties);
  pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condition_properties, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  //edit: previously using malloc
  can_use_pot = (pthread_cond_t*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_cond_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); 
  //---
  pthread_cond_init(can_use_pot, &condition_properties);

  if(pipe(fd) == -1){
    printf("An error ocurred opening pipe\n");
    return -1;      
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(pot_lock);
  printf("[Bear] Places the shared pot\n");
  Pot p = {0, 10};
  if(write(fd[1], &p, sizeof(Pot)) == -1){
    printf("An error ocurred writing pipe\n");
    return -1;  
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(pot_lock);

  int id = -1;
  while(created_bees < total_bees && id != 0){
    id = fork();
    created_bees++;
  }

    if(id == 0){
    while(1 == 1){
      pthread_mutex_lock(pot_lock);
      Pot p;
      if(read(fd[0], &p, sizeof(Pot)) == -1){
        printf("An error ocurred reading pipe\n");
        return -1;  
      }
      if(p.honey >= p.size){
        printf("[Bee] Pot is full. Signals bear\n");
        //edit 2: I was not returning the pot to the pipe
        if(write(fd[1], &p, sizeof(Pot)) == -1){
          printf("An error ocurred writing pipe\n");
          return -1;    
        }
        //---
        pthread_cond_signal(can_use_pot);
      }
      else{
        sleep(1);
        p.honey = p.honey +1;
        printf("[Bee] Places honey in the pot [%d]\n", p.honey);
        if(write(fd[1], &p, sizeof(Pot)) == -1){
          printf("An error ocurred writing pipe\n");
          return -1;    
        }
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(pot_lock);
    }
    }
    else{
    while(1 == 1){
      printf("[Bear] Falls asleep\n");
      pthread_mutex_lock(pot_lock);
      pthread_cond_wait(can_use_pot, pot_lock);
      Pot p;
      if(read(fd[0], &p, sizeof(Pot)) == -1){
        printf("An error ocurred reading pipe\n");
        return -1;  
      }
      sleep(3);
      printf("[Bear] Wakes up and eat [%d]", p.honey);
      p.honey = 0;
      if(write(fd[1], &p, sizeof(Pot)) == -1){
        printf("An error ocurred writing pipe\n");
        return -1;  
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(pot_lock);
    }
    }
}
```

With that I get the following output

```
[Bear] Places the shared pot
[Bear] Falls asleep
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [1]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [2]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [3]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [4]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [5]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [6]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [7]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [8]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [9]
[Bee] Places honey in the pot [10]
[Bee] Pot is full. Signals bear
```

Then it stays there and other times repeats the last message.
For what I understand after the pthread_cond_signal is called and the lock is released, the bear might wake up and do his job. At first I thought that maybe the bear didn't get the chance to acquire the lock, so I tried adding a second condition to tell bees when they can produce, yet it didn't work.

EDIT 1: As pointed out I changed the malloc calls for mutex and cond initialization to mmap, once again I get stuck waiting for the bear to wake up.

Comment: Your memory is not shared between processes. You need to use `mmap` (instead of `malloc`) to create shared mapping and put all data there.

Comment: @StaceyGirl thanks for pointing that out, the examples I found of process-wide mutex just told me to allocate memory no that it had to be shared memory. I've already changed the malloc to mmap, however I get stuck at the same step (output is the same).

Comment: Is there no `[Bear] Falls asleep` in the output? Please add `\n` to your `printf`s in bear to flush the outputs...

Comment: @KamilCuk In my whole life never knew that \n flushes de output. I've added it and  `[Bear] Falls asleep` is now shown

Comment: Your bee reads and writes to the same pipe. Bee after each `write(fd[1]` it does `read(fd[0]`. There is nothing for Bear to read, everything was read by the bee. Your bear waits blockingly on `read(fd[0]` - the pipe is empty. I am having hard time following, if bee is only producing honey, why does it read from the pipe?

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh man that was the problem. I was using the pipe to store the "honey pot". When I checked if the pot was full I was never returning the pot to the pipe. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, then "save"/"store" the honey pot before `thread_cond_signal(can_use_pot);`. That said, the `write(fd[1]` could be placed after `if`. But still, it's strange to `sleep(1)` with the mutex blocked - the whole idea is for producers to produce while not blocking others. I would suggest to refactor the code and write some functions like `pot_is_empty` `pot_add_one` `pot_take_one` - it'll be easier that way.

Comment: @KamilCuk Exactly. I'll refactor the code now to make it more readable. Thank you all :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @StaceyGirl the mutex and conditions must be initialized using shared memory (mmap)

Also, as @KamilCuk realized, the last bee that fills up the pot was not returning it to the pipe before waking up the bear, leaving the bear waiting forever for the data of the pipe.